# A man finds some wrapping paper and gives it as a present to his daughter

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I'm looking for a cartoon (might be Disney but I'm not sure). I watched it some time ago but I don't remember it's title.

It's a story about a piece of wrapping paper. At the beginning a girl from a rich family gets a gift. Greedily she tears off the paper to check out what is inside the box. It's a pretty good present but still she's very unsatisfied. Meanwhile, the wrapping paper flies out through the window and lands near a poor man. He happily takes it with him. When he gets home to his family he gives the paper to his daughter. She is really excited by this present and starts to play with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds very much like [A Gift Of Gold](http://animaniacs.wikia.com/wiki/A_Gift_of_Gold#A_Gift_of_Gold). The synopsis (taken from [TV Tropes.org](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TearJerker/Animaniacs)):

> A piece of shiny gold wrapping paper is used to wrap Mindy's present.
>   Needless to say, she tears it to shreds, but one piece blows out the
>   window. It flits from place to place, trying to find somewhere to
>   settle, before finally landing in a trash can. Just then, a poor man
>   fishes it out of the can, using it to wrap a Cymbal-Banging Monkey,
>   which he gives to his son. The son opens it, then folds the paper
>   carefully and puts it in his pocket, giving it the love it sought the
>   entire cartoon.

The only difference is the final recipient of the paper is a boy, not a girl. You see the animation for yourself and decide if it's the same one: [A Gift Of Gold Animation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlr28u38mtQ)

Comment: Note, with regards to the final line in this post, would any mods/users kindly comment on my post here on the Meta site: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/can-we-suggest-where-to-find-videos-that-may-or-may-not-be-copyrighted